# android, can it put a file in a place would be accessed from both build.gradle and the project

Tags: android, caching, build.gradle

In Android project, there are some file need to be pre download from the server through some internal utility. In the project build time the files will be used to build some local data in the gradle task, and saved to somewhere for app code to consume.

is there a dir/folder being accessible from gradle and the code inside the app?

Answer (score 1):

You [can](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) access any file in the Gradle script and manipulate them differently. For example, reading gitignore in the app module:

```
InputStreamReader(FileInputStream(File(project.rootDir, "app/.gitignore")))
            .readLines()
            .onEach { println(it) }
```

Also, you can add any existing in your project directory to your apps assets:

```
// app/build.gradle.kts
sourceSets {
    getByName("main").assets.srcDir("${project.rootDir.path}/test")
}
```

In general, I see two options:

1. download the file into the app resource directory - then you don't need to add the asset dir in the gradle file
2. download the file in a different directory, somewhere where you want it - you will have to add that directory to app assets in the gradle file
   In both cases, you can access files from gradle files.